# How to check if a radio button is checked or not in jquery?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, partial-page-refresh

I have 3 radio buttons. I want to add some events on the radio check. But I am not able to track it. Any suggestions? I think it's old jquery 1.1.24 and I can not update it for some reason.

jQuery('#myform form input[type="radio"]:eq(0)').prop('checked', true);

Somewhere, I can see those sort of code too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do:

```
function isChecked() {
    return ($('input[type=radio]:checked').size() > 0);
}
```

Comment: I tried that too, but did not work: Here is more detail:
jQuery('#myform form label:eq(0)').click(function() {
   jQuery('#myform form input[type="radio"]:eq(0)').prop('checked', true);
   jQuery('input[name="xcc-code-selected"]').trigger('click');
   console.log("The first button clicked");
   
  });
This is how it is at the moment and I've added my code after the console log. It appears for a while but again the page gets reload and boom. Any suggestion?

Comment: If the page gets reloaded (refreshed) then all the components will be back to default. Which means that the Form as well. Perhaps you need to reload the page partially?